# Textbox background red + white font, when running show gray font

Tags: c#, windows

I need a Textbox to have a red background and a white font, some alarm text. It looks OK when I am in design mode of Visual Studio 2010.

However when I run the app the text becomes gray. I have no idea of why this is. Why should a font color change to something I didn't tell it to do? Is this a bug?

Comment: The text box is probably *disabled*

Comment: sceenshot would help, textboxes can be updated at runtime (programmatically) which would override your design time settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "kashif";
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

[image]

textbox is disabled. enabling it will make you get the disired color. and if you want somebody to not to write something in this and see the white color then make it readonly

```
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```